# Launch EC2 cluster with Whirr

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera, apache-whirr

I am working through the tutorial of Jeffery Breen at the moment. I got some troubles when I would like to launch a ec2 cluster with Whirr. I use a cloudera demo vm cdh3u4.

I downloaded the version 0.8.1 of whirr.

Here are all commands I ran:

```
$ wget http://mirror.switch.ch/mirror/apache/dist/whirr/whirr-0.8.1/whirr-0.8.1.tar.gz
$ tar zxf whirr-0.8.0.tar.gz
$ export PATH="~/whirr-0.8.0/bin:$PATH"

$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MY ACCESS KEY
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=MY SECRET ACCESS KEY

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P hadoop-ec2
```

Then I was asked in which file the key should be safed and I typed: hadoop-ec2

```
$ whirr launch-cluster --config hadoop-ec2.properties
```

...and here is the problem: There were no instances launched! I got the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source hadoop-ec2.properties
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:249)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:229)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:149)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
        at org.apache.whirr.command.AbstractClusterCommand.getClusterSpec(AbstractClusterCommand.java:122)
        at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.run(Main.java:69)
        at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

What I did next is link the properties-file directly to the file that Jeffrey Breen published in his tutorial and then I got the following thing:

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ whirr launch-cluster --config /home/cloudera/TutorialBreen/config/whirr-ec2/hadoop-ec2.properties
Running on provider aws-ec2 using identity ${env:AKIAIXPYW6EBNWSZWMTQ}
Bootstrapping cluster
Configuring template for bootstrap-hadoop-datanode_hadoop-tasktracker
Unable to start the cluster. Terminating all nodes.
org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException: POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 -> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
        at org.jclouds.aws.handlers.ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.refineException(ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.java:123)
        at org.jclouds.aws.handlers.ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.handleError(ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.java:92)
        at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError(DelegatingErrorHandler.java:69)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.shouldContinue(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:197)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.call(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:167) . . .
```

Was this a step into the right direction and if yes, what do I have to do that it works?

I am a very beginner so I'd really appreciate your help and if possible, als "clear" as possible since I am - as I said - a beginner.

The next step would be to run this command:

```
$ whirr run-script --script install-r+packages.sh --config hadoop-ec2.properties
```

I really hope to find some help here so that I can continue with the tutorial.

Whirr-config-File:

```
whirr.cluster-name=hadoop-ec2

# Change the number of machines in the cluster here
whirr.instance-templates=1 hadoop-namenode+hadoop-jobtracker,5 hadoop-datanode+hadoop-tasktracker
# whirr.instance-templates=1 hadoop-namenode+hadoop-jobtracker,1 hadoop-datanode+hadoop-tasktracker

# Uncomment out these lines to run CDH
# You need cdh3 because of the streaming combiner backport
whirr.hadoop.install-function=install_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hadoop.configure-function=configure_cdh_hadoop
# make sure java is set up correctly, requires Whirr >= 0.7.1
whirr.java.install-function=install_oab_java 

# For EC2 set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables.
whirr.provider=aws-ec2
whirr.identity=${env:DFD...(mycode)..DFDSDF}
whirr.credential=${env:df342.(mycode)..3434324}

# The size of the instance to use. See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
whirr.hardware-id=m1.large
# whirr.hardware-id=c1.xlarge

# select recent, 64-bit CentOS 5.6 AMI from RightScale
whirr.image-id=us-east-1/ami-49e32320

# here's what Cloudera recommends:
# whirr.image-id=us-east-1/ami-ccb35ea5

# If you choose a different location, make sure whirr.image-id is updated too
whirr.location-id=us-east-1

# You can also specify the spot instance price
# http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/
# whirr.aws-ec2-spot-price=0.109

# By default use the user system SSH keys. Override them here.
# whirr.private-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa
# whirr.public-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# Expert: override Hadoop properties by setting properties with the prefix
# hadoop-common, hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-mapreduce to set Common, HDFS, MapReduce
# site properties, respectively. The prefix is removed by Whirr, so that for
# example, setting 
# hadoop-common.fs.trash.interval=1440
# will result in fs.trash.interval being set to 1440 in core-site.xml.

# Expert: specify the version of Hadoop to install.
#whirr.hadoop.version=0.20.2
#whirr.hadoop.tarball.url=http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-${whirr.hadoop.version}/hadoop-${whirr.hadoop.version}.tar.gz
```

Comment: Your error suggests some problem with credentials. I can point you to http://www.xmsxmx.com/apache-whirr-create-hadoop-cluster-automatically/ .. hope this helps.

Comment: you need to create a new SSH keypair to be used with whirr, hope you have created that. If not that may be the problem. Other than that, check your AWS credentials. they are not your regular username password.

Comment: I created an ssh keypar using this command: [cloudera@localhost ~]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""

Comment: I added the config file in my post above. Maybe you can check whether all is right there? Thanks.

Comment: you need to provide your priveate key and public key in the config file. In your config file currently, these lines are commented.

Comment: oh ok. So do I just have to take away the # or add the huge number that I find in the key-file? Sorry for beginner question - it's my first time to do something like this and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: whirr.private-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa   Maybe you could show me a sample what I need to do in that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes remove `#`

Sample here:

```
whirr.private−key−file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/whirr_id_rsa
whirr.public−key−file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/whirr_id_rsa.pub
```

repalce `whirr_id_rsa` with your file name. More details here:

http://www.xmsxmx.com/apache-whirr-create-hadoop-cluster-automatically/

Comment: Do you maybe also know an answer to my following question - would be great! [My next question concerning whirr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235767/using-whirr-to-setup-ec2-cluster)